# How to understand data sharing between components?

Tags: angular, angular-components

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

I know this docs tells you how to communicate between a parent and child component. But I'm seriously having a hard time understanding how this works. Maybe it's the example they use. Would someone explain it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple example here: http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

The service code looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;

@Injectable() 
export class DataService { 
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

See the link for the component and module code.